# Deploy docker to on-premise using azure CI-CD

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created.NetCore Application and was successfully deployed to the local PC docker container.

Now I am trying to build it from Azure DevOps and publish it to one of my servers hosted on-premise.

Now I have no idea how to host it. Also not sure what is Docker Registry Service Connection & Container Registry Type.

My DevOps server is also hosted on-premise with no docker installed on it.

I have a docker account with one private repository.

Please suggest how to continue as I am getting the below error while building the image

open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Deploy docker to on-premise using azure CI-CD

If you want to deploy app to the local PC docker container, you can use [Self-hosted Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install)(Build Pipeline and Release Pipeline) or [Deployment Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops)(Release Pipeline).

**Note:** we need set the self-agent on the server where have docker installed.

Then you could try the following pipeline settings.

[image]

Here is a blog about [ASP.Net Application Deployment in Docker for Windows](https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/08/24/asp-net-application-deployment-in-docker-for-windows/).

You could use `Command Line Task` to run the docker command. In this case, you can move the local build and deploy process to azure devops